# Why div gets an additional "style=padding..." attribute in the result HTML if it wasn't in PHP code?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I've been editing a WordPress theme for my needs, but I've faced some issue - `div` block gets a new attribute, but I don't know why.

My WordPress theme code:

```
<div class="header-wrapper"    <?php echo $pexeto_bg_data['color_css'];?> >         
<!-- PRINT WHAT HAS RETURNED FROM FUNCTION: -->
<?php echo $pexeto_bg_data['color_css'];?>
<!-- previous line prints "style="background-color:#FFFFFF;"" ONLY -->
```

but when I open my site in browser and see its source code then `header-wrapper` also has `padding-top` attribute:

```
<div class="header-wrapper" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); padding-top: 161px;">
</div>
```

How is it possible? How can some new attributes can appear in "style"?

Comment: It's probably added by JavaScript.

Comment: You'd have to post all your relevant code if you want any help with this. Right now there is no way to know what is happening.

Comment: @showdev Thanks! I've disabled JavaScript in browser and the new attribute disappeared! 

But now i have to find what js line does it. How it approximately should look like?

Comment: Hard to say. You could try looking for strings like "padding-top". But you might see what JavaScript is loaded and disable them one-by-one to narrow down which one is adding the styles.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, @showdev!
I found this JavaScript code line (among ~5 .js files):

```
self.defaultHeight = self.$el.outerHeight();
```

I added `-10` at the end and got desired changes.